# Insert data from temp table into a new table using a SQL statement in a dynamic variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to save the result of the below query into a new table. The query gets the column names dynamically using a variable @col.

```
QUERY :
---------------

set @sql = 'select id,' + @col +
' from (select id,Column_Name,act_dt_Tm
from #Act_Table) as Source_Table 
PIVOT
(MAX(act_dt_tm)
for column_name in(' + @col+ '))as PIVOT_TABLE';

execute (@sql)

#Act_Table (Temp Table)
 id         Column_Name   act_dt_tm
18418       Col_name_2    2022-04-11
18418       Col_name_3    2022-04-25    
18692       Col_name_2    2022-04-24    
18692       Col_name_3    2022-04-23        
18702       Col_name_1    2022-04-30    
18702       Col_name_2    2022-04-30
18702       Col_name_3    2022-04-21 

New_Table
 id      col_name_1     Col_name_2      Col_name_3
18418   NULL          2022-04-11         2022-04-25 
18692   NULL          2022-04-24         2022-04-23 
18702   2022-04-30    2022-04-30         2022-04-21
```

Below are the 2 solutions that I tried and both return errors:

Solution 1 :

```
 set @sql1 = 'SELECT *
INTO New_Table
FROM (select id,' + @col +
' from (select id,Column_Name,act_dt_Tm
from #Act_Table) as Source_Table 
PIVOT
(MAX(act_dt_tm)
for column_name in(' + @col+ ')) as PIVOT_TABLE';
execute (@sql1)

Error: Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT_TABLE'.

Solution 2 :
set @sql1 = 'SELECT *
INTO New_Table
FROM (' + @sql 

Error: Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT_TABLE'.
```

Comment: @Stu Updating the questions further. Thanks

Comment: Simple question - why? How do you intend to use this table after creation? Once you go down this path of dynamic sql, everything that follows must also be dynamic.

Comment: @smor It's because the column names can vary at different loads. It's actually a data warehouse.

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing testable about the code you've posted, consider adding a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @stu I'll do that. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You don't understand the question. You are attempting a dynamic pivot. You are attempting to then create a table to store that resultset. Even if you manage to complete this successfully, how will you then attempt to use that table?

Comment: @smor This table would be picked by a dashboard which would also dynamically add the get columns. We got this as a requirement from the people building dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to successfully create the new table dynamically. It was a syntax error. I missed this code after PIVOT TABLE in the query") as New_Table"

```
 set @sql1 = 'SELECT *
  INTO New_Table
  FROM (select id,' + @col +
  ' from (select id,Column_Name,act_dt_Tm
  from #Act_Table) as Source_Table 
  PIVOT
  (MAX(act_dt_tm)
  for column_name in(' + @col+ ')) as PIVOT_TABLE) as New_Table';
 
  execute (@sql1)
```

I'll update the question with minimal reproducible example, so it can be used in future.